# Will I publish a new app to AppStore Connect if I make a new scheme with different bundle id for AppStore?

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

The goal is that I want to publish a new app to App Store Connect and not update the existing one. That is why I was wondering if setting a new scheme with different bundleID for App Store will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you create multiple Bundle IDs of the same app it will reject the App Store Review process (Consider as Spam - 4.3)

> Refer - https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#spam